# Redirecting to a second server is not using it's faces-config

Tags: jsf-2.2

I want to store all of my web site's images on  a secondary file server to reduce database and main server work loads (there will eventually be a huge number of image files and the browser makes a totally separate request to load the images so I figured I may as well have a separate file server for them).

I have a standard link to forward users to the file server to allow them to upload picture files for products, however it appears not to be using the file server's faces-config file.

In a JSF page on the main server:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost:12631/FileServer/faces/ExternalSecure/ForwardUploadImagesProcessing.xhtml#{newEditProductBean.uploadPicviewfParamValues}" >Upload replacement image(s) for storage on #{authBackingBean.demoCompany}'s servers</a>
```

The forwarding page 'ForwardUploadImagesProcessing.xhtml' on the file server is as follows:

```
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

            <head>
                <title>redirect</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <f:metadata>
                    <f:viewParam name="path" value="#{uploadImages.path}" />
                    <f:viewParam name="filename" value="#{uploadImages.fileName}" />
                    <f:viewParam name="productTypeName" value="#{uploadImages.productTypeName}" />
                    <f:viewParam name="productModel" value="#{uploadImages.productModel}" />

                    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{uploadImages.processUploadEntityImages()}" />
                </f:metadata>        
            </body>
        </html>
```

The 'processUploadEntityImages()' method in the 'UploadImages' backing bean (see below) is called as expected and the System.out statement prints all of the passed f:viewParam values correctly, however the JSF navigation string 'process_UploadImages' does not load the page that it points to on the file server. How can I force it to switch to the file server and it's faces-config?

In the 'UploadImages' backing bean on the file server:

```
public String processUploadEntityImages()
{
    System.out.println("processUploadEntityImages() " + path + " ; " + fileName + " ; " + productTypeName + " ; " + productModel);

     return "process_UploadImages";
 }
```

In the 'faces-config' of the file server:

```
 <navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>process_UploadImages</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/ExternalSecure/UploadImages.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<managed-bean>
    <description>For uploading thumb and main images for entities. </description>
    <managed-bean-name>uploadImages</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>processing.UploadImages</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

In the web.xml on the file server:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have a link on the index page of the file server that links to this page, and the 'UploadImages.xhtml' page is opened correctly using the 'process_UploadImages' navigation rule, so there is no problem there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I should have known this; I've used it before for redirecting to a JSF page from a link inside an email....

processUploadEntityImages() should look like this:

```
public void processUploadEntityImages()
{
    System.out.println("processUploadEntityImages() " + path + " ; " + fileName + " ; " + productTypeName + " ; " + productModel);

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    NavigationHandler navigationHandler = facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
    navigationHandler.handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "process_UploadImages");
}
```